# Relatório de usuários WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Preciso puxar um relatório com as informações Nome, Cidade, Tipo de Loja e E-mail que foram cadastradas a partir de um formulário de registro.
Existe algum plugin que eu consiga puxar este relatório com estas informações?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você tem que se certificar que essas informações existem no seu banco do Wordpress.

Se o usuário se cadastrou pelo formulário de cadastro comum do Wordpress, não haverá essas informações.

No caso se ele se cadastrou a partir de algum plugin que você tenha, o próprio plugin teria que te exibir essas informações.

O melhor que você tem a fazer é entrar no banco de dados e ver em qual tabela essas informações foram salvas e rodar uma consulta SELECT * from SUA_TABELA, assim poderia visualizar as informações.

Não sei se era isso que você queria, caso contrário tente reformular sua pergunta, já usei Wordpress por muito tempo e conheço bem a base de dados dele, esse tipo de formulário de registro não é padrão dele.

Edit: Você também pode verificar por algumas opções em "Ferramentas" no Wordpress, acredito que seja difícil um plugin que apenas cadastre mas não exiba o que cadastrou.